# Android Calling REST service. Source Not Found

Tags: java, android, rest

This has now come to a point where I cannot take it anymore! i have seen a lot of people have had the same problem as this one but their solution do not work for me.

I am trying to call a REST service from my Android application. I am still new to Android BTW. 
The calling code looks like this:

```
String httpResult = "";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaulthttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
String url = myURL;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myURL);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpContext);

//receive response in input stream
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
//convert the stream into a string
if(is != null){
//call method that will convert stream to string
   httpResult = cString(is);
}else{
   httpResult = "Error";
}
```

When I debug the code, I see that throws an exception when the compiler hits the  `"HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()"` line of code and shows `"No Source Found"` screen.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Did you set in manifest.xml Internet permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest, near <application> tag

Comment: @Mach: the exception is class not found.

Comment: @user974801: Yes I already did that

Comment: @user2248986 Step Over that line of code while debugging. You'll likely find the source of error in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

＂No Source Found＂occurred when you debug a class without the source file.

You should just use F6 to step over when debugging.

Comment: Okay then where do I find the source file for class "org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" because I think this what it cannot resolve

Comment: Get the android sdk source and import it to eclipse. You can get it by Android SDK Manager(find the correct version and select the "Sources for Android SDK"　item)

Comment: I used F6 to step over the code and it turns out twas the XML serialiser that was giving me issues. So i just changed my REST service to return JSON instead and now ALL WORKS WELL!!! yeeeeeeeepi! :)